# String between double quotes using Regex in Java

Tags: java

How can i get Strings between double quotes using Regex in Java?

```
_settext(_textbox(0,_near(_span("My Name"))) ,"Brittas John");
```

ex: I need My Name and Brittas John

Answer (score 3):

Get the matched group from index 1 that is captured by enclosing inside the parenthesis `(...)`

```
"([^"]*)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nI4qQ6/3)

Pattern explanation:

```
  "                        '"'
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more times) (Greedy)
  )                        end of \1
  "                        '"'
```

sample code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher("_settext(_textbox(0,_near(_span(\"My Name\"))) ,\"Brittas John\");");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "_settext(_textbox(0,_near(_span(\"My Name\"))) ,\"Brittas John\");";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
My Name
Brittas John
```

Comment: but it's slow in performance as suggested by me. Look at [regex101 - regex debugger](http://regex101.com/r/nI4qQ6/3) for no of steps. I am not sure that is it giving true result.

Comment: @user3218114 how is the performance any slower? In both cases the parser should stop as soon as it sees a `"`.

Comment: Look at the no of steps needed to extract the desired result. What is the difference between greedy and lazy pattern? which is faster?

Comment: @user3218114 lazy is actually generally faster. It knows exactly when to stop. In this specific case, your greedy should perform equally though. But I still fail to see why it would be any faster.

Comment: @Cruncher look at the demo that I shared you and click on regex debugger link then inspect the steps needed to extract the desired result. Expend all steps.

Comment: Lazy pattern uses BACKTRACK.

Comment: @user3218114 That looks unbelievably bugged, and probably has to do with how they're defining a "step". I don't see why there should be any backtrack, or why your regex is allowed to call the match so much of it a single step. Parsers need to loop through every character...

Comment: @Cruncher do you have any way to test the performance between these two patterns? I also want to know about it.

Comment: @user3218114 Randomly generate a giant file with "'s dispersed through out it. And run it against both regex.